# Get 502.5 with Running the Sample

Tags: iis, asp.net-core, windows-server-2012-r2

On my *Windows Server 2012*,

- I firstly installed the **[.NET Core Windows Server Hosting buddle](https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=817246)**;
- and then **download the [sample](https://github.com/aspnet/IISIntegration/tree/dev/samples/IISSample)** to the Server;
- and then used this line:
  `<aspNetCore processPath="dotnet" arguments=".\IISSample.dll" stdoutLogEnabled="false" stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout" forwardWindowsAuthToken="false"/>`
  for the **web.config**;
- finally set the **IISSample** as the ***Physical Path*** and **Start the Site**;

But I get

> HTTP Error 502.5 - Process Failure

I know it was wrong, but how should I Deploy my Web App to IIS?

- Should I download full dotnet core tools to compile at my Server?
- or use some other ways to deploy?

Thanks very very much for help

Answer (score 0):

Got Fix on [GitHub](https://github.com/aspnet/IISIntegration/issues/246);

Apologize for Asking this naïve Question...

And the solution is:

> @GuardRex :+1: Thank you very much, it was my first time to publish ASP.NET web app, and I made so many mistakes.
>
> > Did you publish (compile) it first? ... then move the assets from the  publish  folder to the server?
>
> Sorry for skipping this step... (I suppose that IIS will compile for us  )
>
> > If so, did you explicitly follow the guidance at https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/publishing/iis.html, including restarting IIS or the server after installing the hosting bundle?
> >
> > *Deploy the Application*
> >     *1. On the target IIS server, create a folder to contain the application’s **assets**.*
>
> I indeed read this article carefully many times, but the **assets** is a bit confusing... I suppose.
>
> A thousand apologies for posting this here...